# How to set SMTP Office365 mail configuration in WSO2 Product

Tags: email, smtp, wso2, smtp-auth, wso2-business-process

we are trying to set SMTP Mail configuration in WSO2 Product. Following steps for set SMTP Mail Configuration in WSO2BPMN Product.

1. Change SMTP Configuration in **`/conf/activiti.xml`**

> ```
> <property name="mailServerHost" value="smtp.office365.com"/>
> <property name="mailServerPort" value="587"/>
> <property name="mailServerDefaultFrom" value="XXX@YYY.COM"/>
> <property name="mailServerUseTLS" value="true"/>
> <property name="mailServerUsername" value="XXX@YYY.COM"/>
> <property name="mailServerPassword" value="XXX"/>
> ```

2. Restart Wso2BPMN product to apply changes in wso2bpmn.

But, we are facing the issue in send mail from Office365 through wso2bpmn product. Here, I have addressed the issue below,

```
 Caused by: org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.office365.com:587
        at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1398)
        at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1423)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.MailActivityBehavior.execute(MailActivityBehavior.java:102)
        ... 192 more
Caused by: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 554 5.2.0 STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:SendAsDeniedException.MapiExceptionSendAsDenied; Failed to process message due to a permanent exception with message Cannot submit message. 16.55847:780E0000, 17.43559:0000000094000000000000000000000000000000, 20.52176:140F9185000010100A00D231, 20.50032:140F9185701710100A00E231, 0.35180:62350000, 255.23226:0A00C931, 255.27962:0A000000, 255.27962:0E000000, 255.31418:0A000000, 16.55847:B2000000, 17.43559:0000000068010000000000000200000000000000, 20.52176:140F9185000010107B350000, 20.50032:140F91857017101080350000, 0.35180:0A00D330, 255.23226:85350000, 255.27962:0A000000, 255.27962:32000000, 255.17082:DC040000, 0.27745:8F350000, 4.21921:DC040000, 255.27962:FA000000, 255.1494:0A007530, 0.37692:04000100, 0.37948:04000100, 5.33852:00000000534D545000040480, 4.56248:DC040000, 7.40748:010000000000010B05000780, 7.57132:000000000000000000000000, 1.63016:32000000, 4.39640:DC040000, 8.45434:DD08C5FEDCC4AE4D81EB3D16E07C62BF00000000, 5.10786:0000000031352E32302E313432352E3030303A414D30505230374D42353436303A65353332653963312D613162352D343633372D383933632D35393263323535396364343300000000000000, 255.1750:2A310000, 255.31418:0A003F32, 0.22753:2F310000, 255.21817:DC040000, 4.60547:DC040000, 0.21966:0A009530, 4.30158:DC040000 [Hostname=AM0PR07MB5460.eurprd07.prod.outlook.com]
```

Please Provide me with any suggestion/idea for this.

Thanks,
Vivek KT.

Answer (score 1):

the same thing happened to me. In my case, the problem is that I have never entered with that email account and it has not been configured. once configured it has worked well for me.

first connect to outlook.com and set up the account and then try wso2.

And i put all that email information in conf/axis2/axis2.xml